# Can't find variable on an if statement used in main

Tags: java

I am trying to create a menu in my program but when I am calling a function the terminal returns that: cannot find symbol. Note that in the code below other methods are not appear. Also without the if statements this code is working.

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    int choose = Integer.parseInt (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Choose an option"));           

    System.out.println("Press 1 to Encrypt");
    System.out.println("Press 2 to Decrypt");
    System.out.println("Press 3 to Bruteforce");


    if(choose==1) 
    { 
        //gets a string to encrypt
        String str = (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input Data to encypt:"));

        //gets a key
        int key = Integer.parseInt (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input the key:"));


        //prints encryption
        String encrypted = encrypt(str, key);
        String frcencrypted = encrypted;
        System.out.println("Encrypted:" + encrypted);
    }

    else if(choose==2)
    {
        //prints decryption
        String decrypted = decrypt(encrypted, key);
        System.out.println("Decrypted:" + decrypted);
    }

    else if(choose==3)
    {   
        //print bruteforce
        bruteforce(frcencrypted);       
    }

    else
    {
        System.out.println("Wrong value");
    }
}
```

And here the errors:

cipher.java:34: error: cannot find symbol

String decrypted = decrypt(encrypted, key);

cipher.java:34: error: cannot find symbol

String decrypted = decrypt(encrypted, key);

cipher.java:41: error: cannot find symbol

bruteforce(frcencrypted);

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a variable inside a block it becomes local variable to that block which means you cant use outside of that block.

In this case you have declared `encrypted` and `frcencrypted` inside `if` block and used it inside `else`, so its not able to find it.

You have to declare it out side of the if block

Answer (score 0):

You have these lines

```
    String encrypted = encrypt(str, key);
    String frcencrypted = encrypted;
```

inside the if block. If you move the declarations before the if block then you make them visible where you want them.

```
String encrypted;
String frcencrypted;
if(choose==1) 
{
```

However I'm not clear how your program will initialise these variables in the decrypt cases. As far as I can see you run the program once and select an single option. How do you intend that encrypted be set when the user selects 2? Should there be a loop around the whole execution?